# Modification of reverse array

Tags: java, arrays, list, reverse

I want to reverse the array elements. The size of array is to be user defined. Can anybody modify this code?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] list = new int[list.length];
    int temp;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Size");
    list = input.nextInt();   // I get an error message here
    System.out.println("Now the reverse is:");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = list.length - 1; i > 0; j--)
        {
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[i];
            list[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" " + list);
}
```

Comment: Actually your first line is wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is two issues -

**1.** You can not declare an array like this -

```
int[] list= new int[list.length];
```

You have to provide array size like this -

```
int[] list= new int[10];
```

Or even -

```
int[] list= new int[N];
```

Where N is an integer

**2.** Input.next() int returns an integer, so you can not assign it with an array like this -

```
list= input.nextInt();
```

You may do something like this -

```
int sizeOfArray;
sizeOfArray = input.nextInt();
```

**3.** You may use one for loop to reverse the array. See the attached code here.

**4.** Finally if the code is re-written with some modification then it would be -

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ReverseArray{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        int temp;
        int sizeOfArray;

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        /*Since array is initialized and populated here 
        * I have remove the size portion to take from user*/
        //System.out.print("Enter Size");
        //sizeOfArray = input.nextInt(); 

        int lastIndex = list.length-1;
        for(int i=0, j=lastIndex; i<j; i++, j--){

            temp = list[j];   
            list[j] = list[i];
            list[i] = temp;

        }

        System.out.println("Now the reverse is:");        
        for(int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go for Collections :

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println("After Reverse Order, ArrayList Contains : " + list);
```

or

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Add elements to ArrayList object
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    System.out.println("After Reverse Order, ArrayList Contains : " + list);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you really want low level answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list= null;
        int temp;
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Size");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        list = new int[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
            list[i] = i+1;
        }
        System.out.println("Original:");
        printArray(list);
        int[] reversed = new int[size];
                for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            reversed[i] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
        }
        System.out.println("Now the reverse is:");
        printArray(reversed);
    }
    private static void printArray(int[] arrayToPrint) {
        for(int i=0; i<arrayToPrint.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println(arrayToPrint[i]);
        }
    }
```

And when I test it the output is:

`Enter Size10
Original:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Now the reverse is:
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1`

Else I recommend to use standard method: `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));`

In your code placement of line `int[] list= new int[list.length];` is problem as you need to put actual size and not `list.length` as array size.